# Is there anyway to set a readonly environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables

I am using the following in openssh/telnet code, which sets the user environment.

```
setenv("TEST_ENV", "testing", 1);
```

But this can be modified by the user, is there anyway to make it readonly env variable?

Comment: Using `[t]csh`?

Comment: No, I am doing it in openssh code.

Comment: As-in `C` code patched into openssh?

Comment: yes, in C. @jordanm

Comment: Then no, you can't restrict child processes from modifying things in it's own environment.

Comment: I was thinking to write these variables data into a 'root' owned file from C code and then read.. But just setenv/getenv seems to make life easier. And the only worry is, data/env can be modified by others. :( Too bad that there is no way to restrict this. :(

Comment: The answer is to find a different approach to your problem that doesn't require relying on environment variables for security. That's not their purpose. A configuration file like you mention sounds like a sensible solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing in the conventional *process environment* to make a variable read only, only shells have that concept for their own environment/variables (the two overlap in ways, but they must be understood as distinct). The same applies for *type* properties like integer, array, function etc.

Have you considered using a restricted shell, like `rbash`? 
You could set `rbash` up to run `readonly TEST_ENV`) in its startup script. `rbash` may be too restrictive though, but it addresses to a good extent the issues raise in the comments.

The environment is a read/write part of each process (see [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/stack-layout.html) and [here](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html) for details), not only can a process write directly to the data part (via `environ[]`), it can change the pointers to it. You might be able to do something with this (i.e. relocate to a read-only page) if you are proficient in assembly and can find your way around the `crt` startup code, but I don't recommend it ;-)

If there are specific commands that users run that must have a certain environment you may be able to set only group-execute and use `sudo` to set the correct variables (e.g. via `/etc/environment` or `env_file` directive) and run the command as the specific group (preserving uid). Recent versions support `noexec` on most platforms which can be used to prevent running a new shell (though can can break programs which legitimately `fork()` and `exec()`).

As a last option you may be able to use `LD_PRELOAD` and your own library to set a controlled environment for some/all user processes by wrapping the relevant libc functions (`getenv() putenv()` etc.). [libfaketime](http://freecode.com/projects/libfaketime) does exactly this for time related libc functions. There's a less well known tool called [timetravel](https://fbo.no-ip.org/svn/fbo/timetravel/) that does similar, but *also* hooks `setenv()` and `getenv()` so as to keep control of `LD_PRELOAD` in the face of adversity.

The most robust approach is to filter the `setenv() unsetenv() putenv()` (and possibly `clearnv()`) calls to prevent modification, and filter `getenv()` so that it always returns the required value (possibly from a file). This approach won't prevent direct manipulation of the environment memory via `environ[]`, but as long as you are in control of `getenv()` any process which relies on the libc API should see your value. `bash` uses `environ[]` directly when it initialises, but also calls `getenv()`.

Answer (score 6):

Readonly variables can be set in POSIX compliant shells using the `readonly` command.

```
readonly VAR=foo   # POSIX
declare -r VAR=foo # bash
export VAR
```

This is in no way a security feature to prevent the user from changing it. The user can always spawn a new shell and change the variable.

Comment: yeah, that is a thing to worry about :(

Comment: Note that `zsh` allows `typeset +r VAR` to turn the readonly attribute off.

Comment: Also note that AT&T implementations of `ksh` export the readonly attribute of exported variables to the environment via the `A__z` special variable, so in a newly started `ksh`, the variable will still be read-only (though if you have access to `env`, or `perl` or any other shell or tool that can modify an environment variable, that won't stop you from doing things like `env VAR=new-value ksh`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `/etc/skel/.bashrc` or every users's `~/.bashrc`

```
readonly TEST_ENV
```